# Does disabling Parent component affect its Child components?

Tags: apache-flex, visible, hbox

I have many buttons in `HBox`.
Instead of disabling each button, I've disabled `HBox`. But I am able to click buttons even though the `HBox` is disabled.
Disabling parent component will not make difference on its child? it shows like disabled but mouse events will generate.
Please can you give me any suggestions?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try also setting the mouseChildren and mouseEnabled to false when you want to have your HBox disabled. That way, clicking of children will also be disabled.

```
myHBox.enabled = false;
myHBox.mouseChildren = false;
myHBox.mouseEnabled = false;
```

Comment: No problem, i'm happy to help. If this solves your problem, also remember to accept the answer :)

Comment: Ok sure I am waiting for any other suggestions.  Disabling parent component will not make difference on its child? it shows like disabled but mouse events will generate.

Comment: Normally, when adding the mouseChildren = false and mouseEnabled = false, the mouse-events will not generate any longer.